# Monotonic fraction vs monotonic difference

Tags: real-analysis, monotone-functions

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $g:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be two differentiable and strictly increasing functions. Consider two statements:

1. $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ is strictly increasing in $x$.
2. $f(x)-g(x)$ is strictly increasing in $x$.

My question is what is the relationship between (1) and (2)? Are they equivalent or does one imply another?

Comment: Just as a background: I'm working on a proof where I have shown that a difference of functions is increasing, but I would actually need that the fraction of these functions is increasing and I cannot seem to find the missing step.

Comment: Of course, (1) is equivalent to $\log f(x) - \log g(x)$ being increasing, but this is not very useful for me.

Comment: (1) is equivalent to $f'g-g'f > 0$, while (2) is equivalent to $f'-g'> 0$. Try to work with these to see that none of the two implies the other one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $f$, $g$ are strictly increasing, $(2)$ implies that $$f'(x)>g'(x)>0 \implies 1>\frac{g'(x)}{f'(x)}$$ while $(1)$ is equivalent to $$f'(x)>\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}g'(x) \implies g(x)>f(x)\frac{g'(x)}{f'(x)}$$ For $x$ such that $f(x)<0$ (if such $x$ exists) you can rewrite the last expression as $$\frac{g(x)}{f(x)}<\frac{g'(x)}{f'(x)}<1$$ So, can you find $f,g$ that violate this, while satisfying all the previous?

---

For example $f(x)=2x+1$ and $g(x)=x$ are both strictly increasing in $\mathbb R$, their difference is clearly $f(x)-g(x)=x+1$ strictly increasing but $$\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=2+\frac1x$$ is decreasing in its domain.

---

**Edit:** The direction $(1) \implies (2)$ is not true either. Consider for example $f(x)=2x$ and $g(x)=3x+1$. Both are strictly increasing, $f(x)/g(x)$ is strictly increasing in its domain, but $f(x)-g(x)=-x-1$ is strictly decreasing.

Comment: Ok, this actually answers my question. Rephrasing a bit: (1) is equivalent to $\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)} > \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ and (2) is equivalent to $\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)} > 1$. Therefore if $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \geq 1$ then (1) $\Rightarrow$ (2) and when $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \leq 1$ then (2) $\Rightarrow$ (1).

Comment: @TomH Actually you answered it by yourself. Sorry, for the sloppy answer. At least (as a save) a came up with an example that satisfies increasing but not strictly increasing. I ll try to come up with some better one.